# Got an error when build APK in android studio (Cannot invoke "java.io.File.equals(Object)" because "current" is null)

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

When build APK through an Android Studio, i got an error said

```
> Task :app:mergeReleaseAssets FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseAssets'.
> Cannot invoke "java.io.File.equals(Object)" because "current" is null

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 48s
76 actionable tasks: 65 executed, 11 up-to-date
```

[image: error build android]

my project structure

[image: gradle]

is there any wrong with my configuration, I'm using React Native ver:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.0"
  },
```

Comment: It would help a lot if your share your whole Gradle file in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by first navigating to : **'android\app\src\main** folder in your app and there create a folder named assets , so hence while bundling react native will create the index.android.bundle in **android\app\src\main\assets** folder.

[image]

Sometimes the folder is also present so you can **delete** this and can just create with the new folder name **assets**.

Hope this will help.